# how to remove the first column of every row?

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble trying to remove the first column from every row.  I have a felling it is my understanding of jquery.

I've tried the following.

```
$("table:eq(2) tr td:first").remove() // this only removed the first cell

$("table:eq(2) tr td:first").each.remove() // didn't notice a difference
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try using td:first-child instead of td:first

See this page for more:
http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

P.S. A couple of suggestions for your jQuery selector:

1. Use a table id or class instead of index identification because if you move your table in the DOM, your selector will break
2. I'm pretty sure you don't need the "tr"

So:

```
 $("#myTable td:first-child").remove()
```

Comment: +1, excellent information. I'd second all of Karim's suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("table:eq(2) tr").each(function(){
   $(this).find("td:first").remove();
});
```

See it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/cnanney/yZQdU/

Edit: I like Karim's answer better :)

`$("table:eq(2) tr td:first-child")` is much cleaner, not to mention more efficient.

Comment: I guess I wasn't using the each function properly. Your solution worked.

Comment: Yeah. I just modified your second attempt to make it work correctly, didn't consider whether or not it was the most efficient solution, which it is not.